# Sorting a Table by Column Header with Jquery in Asp.Net MVC5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use JQuery to sort a table that's being created with Asp.Net's MVC 5, but I'm encountering a weird problem in which the table duplicates itself entirely, table headers and all.

This is my table's forloop for making it's rows:

```
<table id="tableData" class="tableData" >
        <thead>
            <tr id="tblHeader">
                <th>Supplier Code</th>
                <th>Category ID</th>
                <th>Category Description</th>
                <th>Product Description</th>
                <th>Supplier Description</th>
                <th>Last Modified Date</th>
                <th>Last Used Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    <tbody>

        @foreach (Models.RowObject item in Model)
        {
            <tr class="row" id="@item.IdCode">
                <td>@item.SupplierCode</td>
                <td>@tdCategoryId</td>
                <td>@item.CategoryDescription</td>
                <td>@item.ProductDescription</td>
                <td>@item.SupplierDescription</td>
                <td>@item.LastModifiedDate</td>
                <td>@item.LastUsedDate</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

</table>
```

And here's the JQuery I'm currently using:

```
$('#tableData th').each(function (column) {
        $(this).addClass('sortable').click(function () {
            var findSortKey = function ($cell) {
                return $cell.find('.sort-key').text().toUpperCase() + ' ' + $cell.text().toUpperCase();

            };
            var sortDirection = $(this).is('.sorted-asc') ? -1 : 1;
            var $rows = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('tbody tr').get();
            var bob = 0;
            //loop through all the rows and find
            $.each($rows, function (index, row) {
                row.sortKey = findSortKey($(row).children('td').eq(column));
            });

            //compare and sort the rows alphabetically or numerically
            $rows.sort(function (a, b) {
                if (a.sortKey.indexOf('-') == -1 && (!isNaN(a.sortKey) && !isNaN(a.sortKey))) {
                    //Rough Numeracy check                          

                    if (parseInt(a.sortKey) < parseInt(b.sortKey)) {
                        return -sortDirection;
                    }
                    if (parseInt(a.sortKey) > parseInt(b.sortKey)) {
                        return sortDirection;
                    }

                } else {
                    if (a.sortKey < b.sortKey) {
                        return -sortDirection;
                    }
                    if (a.sortKey > b.sortKey) {
                        return sortDirection;
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            });

            //add the rows in the correct order to the bottom of the table
            $.each($rows, function (index, row) {
                $('tbody').append(row);
                row.sortKey = null;
            });

            //identify the column sort order
            $('#tableData th').removeClass('sorted-asc sorted-desc');
            var $sortHead = $('th').filter(':nth-child(' + (column + 1) + ')');
            sortDirection == 1 ? $sortHead.addClass('sorted-asc') : $sortHead.addClass('sorted-desc');

            //identify the column to be sorted by
            $('td').removeClass('sorted').filter(':nth-child(' + (column + 1) + ')').addClass('sorted');
        });
    });
```

For some reason, the JQuery ends up duplicating the rows and table headers in the same table instead of actually sorting them. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this is happening?

Comment: The fiddle works fine in Safari. http://jsfiddle.net/1a9hvgy9/ is this browser specific?

Comment: @B2K That's so strange. It duplicates the table when I run it from Visual Studio.

Comment: Also from a coding standpoint, I tend to avoid grandparent, great-grandparent references. Try `$(this).closest('table').find('tbody tr')` instead.

Comment: Possibly a timing issue? Do you have this in dom ready or onload?

Comment: @B2K I've tried having it in dom ready or onload but I still get the issue of the table repeating.